# Python Pygame winning diagonal move isnt working

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a Connect Four game in python using Pygame, but I'm stuck right now.

The horizontal and vertical winning moves are working, but the diagonal from the top left corner to the right bottom is not working, though from the left bottom to the top right corner is working. I can't find the problem. Maybe someone can help me out?

My code:

```
def controleer_winnaar(beurt):

    for x in range(RIJEN - 3):
        for y in range(KOLOMMEN):
            #berekening voor verticaal winnen
            if(bord[x][y] == beurt and bord[x + 1][y] == beurt and bord[x + 2][y] == beurt and bord[x + 3][y] == beurt):
                return True

    for x in range(RIJEN):
        for y in range(KOLOMMEN - 3):
            # berekening voor horizontaal winnen
            if (bord[x][y] == beurt and bord[x][y + 1] == beurt and bord[x][y + 2] == beurt and bord[x][y + 3] == beurt):
                return True

    for x in range(RIJEN - 3):
        for y in range(KOLOMMEN - 3):
            # berekening voor schuin-omhoog winnen
            if (bord[x][y] == beurt and bord[x + 1][y + 1] == beurt and bord[x + 2][y + 2] == beurt and bord[x + 3][y + 3] == beurt):
                return True

    for x in range(RIJEN - 3):
        for y in range(KOLOMMEN - 3):
            # berekening voor schuin-omlaag winnen
            if (bord[x][y] == beurt and bord[x + 1][y - 1] == beurt and bord[x + 2][y - 2] == beurt and bord[x + 3][y - 3] == beurt):
                return True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the loop limits wrong: you need to shift the rectangle of your starting points, so that the column values are in the correct range:

```
for x in range(RIJEN - 3):
    for y in range(3, KOLOMMEN):
        # berekening voor schuin-omlaag winnen
        if (bord[x][y] == beurt and bord[x + 1][y - 1] == beurt and bord[x + 2][y - 2] == beurt and bord[x + 3][y - 3] == beurt):
            return True
```

In *this* case, you have proper values for `y`:`y-3`, which will reach into the far corner, and not run off the opposite end of `bord`.

Comment: Sorry, but i dont understand what you mean. What do i need to change right now?

Comment: The rectangle of legal starting points for your diagonal.  For the "reverse" diagonal, you can't iterate from (0,0) to (6-3, 7-3) [assuming a 6x7 board], because your line-of-four tries to immediately move off the board.  You need to move the starting point to (0,3) and end at (6-3,7).